# How to get the user's email from the token in the controller?

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring Security. I have a JWT token filter which is checking all requests' authorization tokens to be valid. As far as I understand, if a token is not valid, the request would be cancelled with an error.

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String token;
        final String email;

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        token = authHeader.substring(7);
        email = tokenProvider.getUserEmail(token);
        if (email != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){

            // User is not yet authenticated (not connected)
            UserDetails user = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
            if (tokenProvider.isTokenValid(token, user)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user, null, user.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public String getEmailFromHeader(String header){
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            throw new UserNotExistException();
        }

        String token = header.substring(7);
        String email = tokenProvider.getUserEmail(token);
        return email;
    }
}
```

I want the user to be able to receive some data from the controller only by his own token. Now I have a method in the controller that retrieves the token from the header:

```java
@GetMapping("/friends")
public ResponseEntity<Set<User>> getFriends(@RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String header){
    String email = tokenFilter.getEmailFromHeader(header);
    User user = service.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null){
        throw new UserNotExistException();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(user.getFriends());
}
```

Is there some way to avoid getting the token from the header in every controller? How could I get the user's email immediately after authentication in the JWTTokenFilter?

Comment: To the get the user's email , create a  regular POJO class with all the user details you want to get from the token. Then create a response entity for that same POJO class that would be the implementation of your friends controller. You can check this article for guidance https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-security-jwt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has passed authentication, you can get user info from security context holder

This is security, it set username to security context holder:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final AccessTokenUtil accessTokenUtil;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String email =null;
        if (token != null && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = token.substring(7);
            try {
                email = accessTokenUtil.getEmailFromJwt(token);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Not Valid");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("Expired JWT token");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something wrong");
            }
            if (email != null && accessTokenUtil.checkExpireDate(token) && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(email);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController{

  private Users getCurrentUser() {
    String login = 
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    if (login != null && !login.equals("anonymousUser")) {
        Optional<Users> optionalUsers = userRepo.findByEmail(login);
        return optionalUsers.orElse(null);
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

getCurrentUser() method return currentUser, if you want to get username you can return login, login is username

Comment: This is actually what I need! But I have one concern. As far as I understand, this Authentication instance is a singleton for the whole app. Will this work fine with a large volume of users?